# Php sessions rename issue

Tags: php

i have this simple question please.

I have this part of code which sets my session:

```
if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "admin.php"
        session_register("admin");
        session_register("password");
        $_SESSION['name']= $myusername;
        header("location:index.php");
    }
```

And this is what i put in every file to protect it :

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
define(ADMIN,$_SESSION['name']); //Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){//If session not registered
header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
}
else //Continue to current page
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
?>
```

I need to change the session name because i already have one like this.

Thanks

Comment: `session_register` is deprecated/obsolete for a long time (it was removed in PHP 5.4). You can simply add something to the `$_SESSION` array to "register" it.

Comment: Can you please be more specific please? and how do i rename the session name on this?...

Comment: @LaMyse: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: you can just use `$_SESSION['new name of your chosing'];`

Comment: What variable are you trying to rename?

Comment: My problem is that i need to create two sessions, one for the admin one for the subadmin... in order that i can give one permission to the admin and one other to the subadmin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, stop to use the [session_register()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) function, it has been DEPRECATED and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

You should write the first part like below:

```
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "admin.php"
    $_SESSION['admin']    = $admin;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['name']     = $myusername;

    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Analysing the second part, the `if/else` logic is inverted. This is the right logic.

```
session_start(); //Start the session

//Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
define(ADMIN, $_SESSION['name']); 

if( isset($_SESSION['admin']) )
{
    //Continue to current page
    header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
}
else
{
    //If session not registered
    header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, in fact i used once the non depreciated version it just didn't work well, but i guess because of the way i inserted the code... well, now can you please tell me about how can i create two sessions?...

Comment: @LaMyse You create only ONE session per user, in each session you store as many vars you want !

Comment: @LaMyse, Why do you want to create two sessions? Isn't there a better way to implement this?

Comment: See the point is , i have a folder with the name subadmin and a folder with the name admin, each of them have different passwords, but i don't want that the subadmin to access in the admin pannel.. that's why i'm asking.. i don't know how to do it!

Comment: I don't have time to do it in a more efficient way, and i don't have the capacity to do it... i have found this easier way, just for now..

Comment: @LaMyse, I think is better you create a flag to indicate when the user is a admin. For instance, you can create a session variable called `$_SESSION['admin_auth']`, if its content is "1" the user is authenticated as admin, else, he isn't authenticated as admin. Based on this, you can give or deny the access to the page.

Comment: Hmm then i'm going to see for what you told me... well, thank you, :) you've helped me enough! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create the illusion of two sessions for the same browser by storing an array in `$_SESSION`:

```
$adminsession = array();
$adminsession['admin'] = ...;
$adminsession['name']  = ...;

$subadminsession = array();
$subadminsession['admin'] = ...;
$subadminsession['name']  = ...;

$_SESSION = array('adminsession'    => $adminsession,
                  'subadminsession' => $subadminsession);
```

And on the next page:

```
$adminsession    = $_SESSION['adminsession'];
$subadminsession = $_SESSION['subadminsession'];
```

In reality this is just one session because a single browser can have only one session open to your site at any one time.

Think carefully about why you think you need this. Is this maintainable? Will your code be easy to understand? Maybe you need to step back and think over your system design?

Comment: Hey thanks, i just need that the users that have adminsession not to access in subadminsession...